# How to have non-required validation rules in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do some form validations in Laravel 5.8,

But even on the fields that don't have the `required` rule, it throws error...

for example:

```
request()->validate([
    'username' => ['required','alpha_num','max:40'],
    'email'   => ['email','max:100'],
]);
```

If I leave the `email` field "empty" (it is not required) on the form it fails to submit and shows this error: `The email must be a valid email address.`

I don't understand, why is this happening? and what is the use of `required` rule when this is the behavior of Laravel validation?

Coming from CodeIgniter community, this is confusing.

Should I also include `nullable` rule in fields that can be empty?

Comment: It's because null or an empty string isn't a valid email address. If you want to also accept null, include `nullable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should include `nullable` in fields that can be empty.

It's something that I found a little tricky when I first used Symphony (upon which Laravel is based).  If you add a validation rule to a field, the validation rule does not allow for a `null` value unless the field is also marked as `nullable`.

The reason you're getting the reported error is because you're forcing the `email` field to pass the `email` validation rules - which, of course, it doesn't if left empty.

Comment: Thanks, but then what is the use of `required` rule?

Comment: `required` says that field must be present in the request body. If you left out your `email` field entirely, you wouldn't get a validation error. Right now you're submitting `email` but it's empty.

Comment: @J.Doe -  I asked myself the same question.  It helps to think of your Symphony / Laravel application as existing in 2 separate parts - each of which is ignorant of the other.  Symphony / Laravel allows you to build APIs (back-ends) which exist independently of a UI (front-end) - in fact I've used Symphony to build several APIs that never had a front-end form accompany them. When using validators, you're setting up rules for how the back-end expects to receive data, and each validator automatically assumes that the data will be present unless you specify otherwise.